# how do I allow free usage of enum and enum class member?

Tags: c++

```
enum class A
{
  ORANGE,
  APPLE
};
...
{// workspace brackets

  if(B == ORANGE){...} // use it like this
}// end of workspace
```

instead of keep using `B==A::ORANGE`, what can I do to make it like `B==ORANGE` within my workspace such as `using namespace std`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only do this in c++ 20 onwards with
`using enum A`

```
enum class foo {
    a,
    b,
    c
};
int main() {
    {
        using enum foo;
        foo f = b;
    }

    {
        //foo f = b; // does not compile
    }
}
```

Comment: is there anyway to do it in c11?

Comment: None that I know of. You can fallback to plain `enum` though.